# A question on support of a $C^{\infty}$ function.

Tags: distribution-theory

We have to show that the $\text{supp}(fT)\subseteq \text{supp} (T)$ where $f$ is a $C^{\infty}$function.
What i want to know is if we can say this $\langle fT, \phi\rangle = \langle T, f\phi\rangle $? 
Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Please give more information. What are $f, T, \phi$? What space are we considering the inner product on?

Comment: @G.Chiusole $T$ is a distribution, $f$ is a $C^{\infty}$ function and $\phi$ is a test function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by definition $\langle fT, \phi\rangle = \langle T, f\phi\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you so much!